# Launching Spyder yields DLL importing error during `import zmq`

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I receive the following error whenever I attempt to launch Spyder:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 6, in 

from spyder.app.start import main
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 22, in 
import zmq

File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in 
from zmq import backend

File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)

File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value

File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)

File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)

File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,


ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This is an Anaconda 3 installation on Windows. How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This usually happens if you used pip to install pyzmq or other packages that depend on it. If that's the case, I'm afraid you'll have to remove and reinstall Anaconda to fix this problem.

Comment: I would at least attempt `conda install pyzmq` before a full reinstall. This can also happen if mixing channels, e.g., `pyzmq` from **anaconda** channel and `zeromq` from **conda-forge**. Please add the output of `conda list '(pyzmq|zeromq)'` to the question body.

Comment: thanks alot merv, i tried conda install pyzmq, and it upgraded the library. solved the error with that